# UI is messed up in all apps with assets after deleting Xcode 7 and installing Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode

I've accidentally updated my **Xcode 6.4** to **Xcode 7.1**, then deleted it (not only **xcode.app** but **/Developer directory within the library directory too**), reinstalled **Xcode 6.4** and now getting errors in the log:

```
[CUIThemeRendition newImageFromCSIDataSlice:ofBitmap: usingColorspace:] Unsupported pixel format in CSI got 1114293
```

UI is totally messed up.
[image]

Does anybody know how to fix this? Actually, I would be satisfied with the correct answer on how to properly delete ALL Xcode related stuff and reinstall it. (I searched a lot about deleting Xcode and can confirm that putting Xcode.app to trash is NOT enough. I need some kind of cleaning.)

UPDATE: My broken Xcode also quits "unexpectedly" on tapping on any storyboard/xib file.

Comment: What was wrong with 7.1 ?

Comment: Well, I have certain customer requirements to develop on Xcode 6.4 only until we move to support iOS9.

Comment: you don't have long till that will be mandatory...

Comment: yeap, I know, but still..I really need Xcode 6.4 working right now

Comment: I have the same problem - did you find a solution?

Comment: @Seb, unfortunately not yet, looks like xcode versions have some conflicts in shared resources.